# Windows won't update and there's no "Windows Update" in Services

Tags: windows, windows-update

My computer won't update.

I went to the Services folder and I don't have a "Windows Update" folder. I don't think my computer has updated for quite sometime and I'm sure it's well over due for one.

I just defragmented it as well, if that helps the problem. I keep an external hardrive with all my pictures, business and Illustrator files on it, to keep my computer free from big files and running better.

Answer (score 1):

Try contacting http://windowsupdate.microsoft.com.  Yes, it is generally a good idea to keep your system patched, however, remember that as old patches fix old problems it is possible to introduce new problems with the patches.

Comment: I cant get my computer to update at all. There is an error message that says it cant because the service isnt running. I went to the services folder to check to see if its running or not and there is no "Windows Update" folder. Any other suggestions??